# What is the spelled-out form of SA in Nestlé SA?

Tags: abbreviations

The Wikipedia page of Nestlé writes the full name of the company as Nestlé S.A.
What does the S.A. stand for?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about the English language.

Comment: Though _S.A._ does indeed stand for a foreign phrase, the abbreviation _S.A._ shows up occasionally in English-language text, and (as I note in my answer) there is an entry for "S.A. (corporation)" in the English language version of Wikipedia, which begins by saying "S.A. (and variants) designates a type of corporation in countries that mostly employ civil law." That suggests to me that "S.A. corporation" may be a legitimate English-language concept. If so, I think that a question about what _S.A._ means or signifies in English is on topic.

Comment: @Sven Yargs: It makes sense that in a field like law, where precise terminology is important, some foreign terms may be imported rather than translated. Note that the Wikipedia article lists use of the abbreviation in many other languages, but English is *absent* from the list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*S.A.* stands for *Société Anonyme*—that is, *anonymous company*, *anonymous partnership*, or *share company*. You can read about the term in the Wikipedia article [S.A. (corporation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.A._%28corporation%29).

As you may already know, Nestlé is incorporated (and headquartered) in Switzerland, where the *S.A.* designation is often used for corporations.

Comment: It is no different to the terms *PLC* (public Limited Company), *Ltd*, *Inc* (Incorporated) or in Germany *GMBH*.  It merely indicates that the business is registered as a company and subject to those laws of ownership etc.

Comment: @WS2 In fact, a *société anonyme* is closer to a German *Aktiengesellschaft* or AG (both names are used in Switzerland). A GmbH is a Sàrl, which also exists in Switzerland.

Comment: @Sven I upvoted your answer but, while it should be obvious to many readers, it might make sense to specify that the name comes from the French language.